# Why does jQuery.fadeTo not animate if toggleClass is called in the callback?

Tags: jquery, toggleclass, fadeto

I have a modal box that starts with a class "hidden" which makes the modal `display: none;` (To keep the invisible modal from capturing mouse clicks)

To fade in the modal I do

```
jQuery('#modalID').toggleClass('hidden'); <-- Makes the modal display: block; by removing the "hidden" class
jQuery('#modalID').fadeTo(.3, 1.0);
```

Which works perfectly. The problem is when I try to toggle the "hidden" class back on after a fade out (to make it display:none: again). When I try to toggle the "hidden" class in the fadeTo callback the modal just disappears instantly. Here's my code

```
jQuery('#modalID').fadeTo(.3, 0, function(){
    jQuery('#modalID').toggleClass('hidden'); <-- *should* make the modal display:none AFTER fading it out....
});
```

I've tried to explicitly add the class in the fadeTo callback

```
jQuery('#modalID').fadeTo(.3, 0, function(){
    jQuery('#modalID').addClass('hidden');
});
```

and even tried ignoring the callback altogether and just putting the commands back to back...

```
jQuery('#overlayID').fadeTo(.3, 0); jQuery('#overlayID').toggleClass('hidden');
```

How can I fade the modal out, and then add the "hidden" class back to the modal afterwords?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is due to your `duration` parameter. It's given in miliseconds, so your setting of `.3` means `0.0003` seconds. Hence the fade appears instantaneous, and the callback immediately triggered.

To fix this, presumably, you want the animation to last 0.3 seconds, so the value should be `300`. Try this:

```
$('#modalID').fadeTo(300, 0, function(){
    $(this).toggleClass('hidden');
});
```

Also note that you could just use `fadeOut()` and avoid the use of the second parameter for opacity.

Comment: But on the fadTo I used .3 and it fades out perfectly, in .3 seconds

Comment: I don't see how that's possible: .3: https://jsfiddle.net/6yLtvc38/, 300: https://jsfiddle.net/6yLtvc38/1/

Comment: This definately isn't the issue. Changing it to 300 made it WAAAAAAY slower on the fade in. The fade in with .3 works perfectly. It's just the fade out

Comment: I see your fiddles. But that's not what I'm experiencing. I do see in the console that it says "JQMigrate is installed 1.4.1"... no idea what that even is. Maybe this WP Theme doesn't actually use jQuery? If I try to load up jQuery manually, it breaks stuff :(

Comment: OK, So I loaded up jQuery V 3.1.1 manually. Broke some other stuff, but I'm just trying to see if that's the issue. (Now, I DID have to use Milliseconds) But the animation is WAY less smooth, and the problem still persists. Fade in works, fade out is instant...

Comment: It sounds like you're maybe using another library which has prototyped the `fadeIn()` method which is why only that one works. In plain old jQuery you would definitely have an issue - as you can see in the fiddle examples.